# c++ return type from function

Tags: c++, arrays

In this example I want return `int nums[40]`
How can I do it?

```
<RETURNTYPE> test()
{
    int nums[40];

    for (int i=0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745260/c-return-array-from-function

Comment: Why not use an `std::vector` instead of an array?

Comment: std::vector is ok, but I want `int[]` in the example.

Comment: you can always [convert a vector to a c-style array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c) when needed. Imho best practice is to convert it **only** when needed, thus even if the client code needs a `int[]` I would use a vector in the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that. For several reasons (including history, and C compatibility, and the rule that decays arrays to pointers in several important cases) you cannot return a raw array; but you can return a `struct` (or `class`....) containing that array.

What you could do in C++11 is to return a [`std::array<int,40>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) ; it behaves like your thing, but it is a proper class (with all the usual operations you imagine, and iterator stuff too). So your code becomes:

```
std::array<int,40> test(void) {
  std::array<int,40> nums;
  for (int i=0; i < 40; i++) {
    nums[i] = i + 1;
  }
  return nums;
}
```

An [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. `g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++11` .... using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) will optimize that exactly like your hypothetical return type (or like [FISOCPP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34774843/841108), which is likely to get compiled into the same object code).

If the size (40) can vary at runtime, use `std::vector<int>` as the type and declare `std::vector> nums{40};`  -then you later could `nums.resize(17);` and the data would then stay in heap (so there is a tiny performance penalty).

Answer (score 2):

The *only* way to achieve that is to encapsulate your array into a structure (or union - which is not relevant).

```
typedef struct { int ra[20]; } rvtyp;

rvtyp test()
{
    int nums[40];

    for (int i=0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    }

    return *(rvtyp*)&nums;
}
```

Then you can access your returned value by 'test().ra'.

Comment: Have to do I release after that? I mean is it heap or stack?

Comment: It's the "stek". Every variable presumably would be stored there (you should consult the ISO standard for concrete information). However you could have a pointer to non-stack memory (which is often fed by calling a function). In our case we are not returning a pointer and no external function is called so you could assume it's the stack.

So no external work is needed for the calling function.

Comment: That's not true - I'm copying the local variable 'nums' to the return-value. So there is no undefined behavior as far as I know. I'm returning the whole array - not a pointer to it.

Comment: If you edit your answer I would be able to upvote it. I wrongly downvoted it!

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamically allocate memory (it is on stack now). Return type will be int * then.